# Need to run xscreensaver in ONE of the TWO monitors in a multihead setup - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, screensaver

I have a multihead setup with two monitors, running Ubuntu 12.04. 
How to make xscreensaver run in one monitor. Need only one of the following lines present, on invoking xscreensaver.

xscreensaver: 10:25:41: already running on display :0.0 (window 0x1c00001) from process 3528 (user@user-desktop).

xscreensaver: 10:25:41: already running on display :0.0 (window 0x1c00005) from process 3528 (user@user-desktop).

Setting the environment variable XSCREENSAVER_WINDOW may solve it, but how to get the window-id?

Please help